# Remove IP range from System Administrator Profile

Tags: profile, login-errors

I have added IP restriction to one of my dev org but now I am not able to login into that salesforce org. It seems that my IP address has been changed and because of this I am facing the issue.

Can anyone please suggest the way to remove the IP range ?

Comment: Contact support? It might be worth to start down that path in case it is your only option.

Comment: Can you please tell me how to contact support ?

Comment: A good question. Typically you would login to your Salesforce org and raise a case from the Help link that appears next to your name. In your case you can't login, so that isn't really an option. Try [help.salesforce.com](http://help.salesforce.com/HTUnauthContactSupport)

Comment: This also requires to login into salesforce org. Can you please tell me the contact support email Id so that I can directly send a email to them ?

Comment: Try phoning them [http://help.salesforce.com/HTViewSolution?id=000001000](http://help.salesforce.com/HTViewSolution?id=000001000)

Comment: Or send an email: support@salesforce.com

Comment: Am curious, did you try appending your password with your security token before contacting support or posting here?

Comment: @crmprogdev - Yes, I have already tried this.

Answer (score 3):

Salesforce support are the only people that can help you. Usually they make you jump through some hoops for "security reasons" but this isn't uniformly enforced. Some will even tell you they can't do anything for you, so it takes some effort. The moral of the story is to never mess with a feature that can irrevocably lock you out unless you're willing to risk losing the account. Only paid customers can get their account fixed, while developers are usually told they are out of luck, unless it is an ISV developer org that they need for their business. Non-paying users are ignored, and have historically always been so.

Comment: The problem has been solved by salesforce support. Thanks for your solution :)